# usort within a custom function in php

Tags: php, usort

I am trying to make a really cool super sort function, however the user sort functionality doesn't work when created as a funtion inside. The idea is to name the array and key then it returns the sorted array according to my choice.

```
function super_sort($key,$arr){
  usort($arr, function($a, $b){
      return strcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
  });
  print_sorted($key,$arr);
}
```

I would call it like this

```
  super_sort('name',$people);
```

also I should add the print_sorted function is this

```
function print_sorted($key,$arr){
  echo '<h1>'.$key.'</h1>';
  foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    echo '<strong>name:</strong> '.$v['name'].'<strong> age:</strong> '.$v['age'].'<strong> social:</strong> '.$v['social'].'<strong> index:</strong> '.$v['index'].'<br/>';
  }
}
```

Comment: import the `$key` by using `use` inside the usort anonymous function, see the answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$key` doesn't exist in the context of your anonymous function so pass it using `use`.

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) use ($key) {
    return strcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
});
```

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Haha that is perfect. You are a genius. I will check your answer as soon as the site allows me. on a side note, maybe you could answer this. Is there an easy way to get the usort to return the order backwards?

Comment: @ThomasValadez, You can just use !strcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]) to make the order backwards.

Comment: @ThomasValadez, You can also also use strcmp($b[$key], $a[$key]) for reverse ordering. Just swapping the values will do the trick. :)